# How to reference entity by uuid in TypeORM Relational Query Builder to add another entity

Tags: many-to-many, typeorm, uuid

## Background

You can see the TypeORM documentation on [Relational Query Builder](https://typeorm.io/relational-query-builder) here. It is using a numeric `id` for its example. But I am using `uuid` for entities.

## Saving entity

In many-to-many scenario, one can use `of` and `add` to add an entity to another, such as:

```js
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of(1).add(3)
```

This works where the `Post` entity has a numeric `id` as its `PrimaryGeneratedColumn`:

```js
@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToMany(() => Category)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[]
}
```

But in the case of using `uuid`, this saving approach does not work:

```js
@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') // using 'uuid' strategy
  uuid: string // which generates a string with 'uuid' format

  @ManyToMany(() => Category)
  @JoinTable()
  categories: Category[]
}
```

and then:

```js
const postUuid = "53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d"
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of(postUuid).add(3)
```

I have tried the following with no luck:

```js
const postUuid = "53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d"

// Does not work
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of({ postUuid: postUuid }).add(3)


// Does not work
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of({ uuid: postUuid}).add(3)


// Does not work
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of(postUuid).add(3)
```

The only way to get this to work is to actually find the entity and reference it:

```js
const postUuid = "53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d"
const post = await dataSource.getRepository(Post).findOne({ where: { uuid: postUuid} })

// Works
await dataSource.createQueryBuilder().relation(Post, "categories").of(post).add(3)
```

Do you have any idea how I can save this post without *finding* / *loading* it first? I'd like to only pass the `uuid` as reference.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to successfully insert the relation `Post.categories` with the exmaple that you shared:

```
        const postId = '53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d';

        await dataSource
            .createQueryBuilder()
            .relation(Post, "categories")
            .of(postId)
            .add(3)
```

These are the entities:

```
@Entity()
export class Post {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid') // using 'uuid' strategy
    uuid!: string // which generates a string with 'uuid' format

    @ManyToMany(() => Category)
    @JoinTable()
    categories?: Category[]

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 45, nullable: false, unique: true})
    name!: string
}
```

```
@Entity()
export class Category {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int' })
    id?: number;

    @ManyToMany(() => Post)
    posts?: Post[]

    @Column({ type: 'varchar', length: 45, nullable: false, unique: true})
    name!: string
}
```

When executing the process, this is TypeOrm's query output:

```
query: INSERT INTO `post_categories_category`(`postUuid`, `categoryId`) VALUES (?, ?) -- PARAMETERS: ["53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d",3]
```

I replicated this using TypeORM version 0.3.17

Perhaps could you share what errors are you getting?
Do these entities exist in your database? (Post with uuid `53c06b96-0945-4dd0-b19e-e3b57e0fc66d` and category with id `3`)

I also tried inserting the relation with the category defined with a uuid as well and I obtained the same result so it seems that TypeORM is handling appropiately these relations (either with uuid or INT)

Comment: Thank you Jose, thank you for your patience. I'll try again and let you know how it goes.